# Transition probabilities for one activity to the other, such as from work to traveling, for every minute of the day

Tags: r, dataframe

[I would like to identify the probability of an activity changes across time.](https://flowingdata.com/2015/12/15/a-day-in-the-life-of-americans/)  Below is an example (from act1_1 to act1_16) of matrix that I was using to calculate transition probabilities between activities.

head (Activities) will return
    a tibble: 6 x 145

```
  serial act1_1 act1_2 act1_3 act1_4 act1_5 act1_6 act1_7 act1_8 act1_9  act1_10
     1  110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    
     2 110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    
     3 110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    
     4 110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    
     5 110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    
     6 110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    110    

# ... with 134 more variables: act1_11 <dbl+lbl>, act1_12 <dbl+lbl>,
```

The dimension of the "Activities" matrix is ncol=144 and nrows=16533; act1_1...ac1_144 are time-steps, and time is represented in 10 minutes intervals (e.g. act1_1 = 4.10am; act1_2=4.20am..). Time start from 4am (act1_1) and ends at act1_144(4am).The columns are filled in with different activities, such 110=sleep, 111=watching Tv, 123=eating, etc.

Below the function that I am using to [calculate the transition probabilities](https://akshayjoshi.space/markov-chain/):

```
transition.matrix <- function(X, prob=T)
{
    tt <- table( c(X[,-ncol(X)]), c(X[,-1]) )
    if(prob) t <- tt / rowSums(tt)
    tt
}
I call the function as:

transitionfunction <- trans.matrix(as.matrix(Activities))
```

Using this function I managed to calculate the transition probabilities between activities (Activities matrix).

But how can I calculate the transitions for every minute of a day?

Comment: I think the last line of your function should return `t`.

Comment: @Edward true thre is a mistake the code should be tt<-tt/rowSums(tt)

Comment: Ah - yes. That's makes much more sense. ;)  Answer updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply` with `rep(..., each=10)`.

Assuming your data is as you say, then the following command will expand the data frame from one with 145 columns (serial + 144 10-minute intervals in one 24-hour period) into one with 1,441 columns (serial + 1440 1-minute intervals in one 24-hour period).

```
Activities1 <- data.frame(Activities[,1], 
                          t(apply(Activities[,-1], 1, FUN=rep, each=10)))

names(Activities1) <- c("serial", paste("act1", seq_len(1440), sep="_"))
dim(Activities1)
#[1] 16533  1441
```

Concerning your function, I've corrected the error according to your comment.

```
transition.matrix <- function(X, prob=T)
{
  tt <- table( c(X[,-ncol(X)]), c(X[,-1]) )
  if(prob) tt <- tt / rowSums(tt)
  tt
}
```

And probably omit the serial column when calling the function. Here's the result for the 10-minute intervals:

```
transitionfunction <- transition.matrix(as.matrix(Activities[,-1]))
transitionfunction

#       110   111   123
# 110 0.334 0.332 0.333
# 111 0.334 0.333 0.332
# 123 0.332 0.333 0.335
```

Given that the data is random (see below), the result looks reasonable

Now for the 1-minute intervals. You'll have to wait about 1 minute due to the larger size of the data.

```
transitionfunction <- transition.matrix(as.matrix(Activities1[,-1]))
transitionfunction

 #       110    111    123
 # 110 0.9338 0.0331 0.0331
 # 111 0.0332 0.9337 0.0331
 # 123 0.0331 0.0331 0.9338
```

Given that we repeated each activity 10 times, the results seem correct.

---

**Data** (simulated):

```
n <- 16533
ncol <- 144    
set.seed(404)

Activities <- data.frame(serial=1:n,
                           matrix(sample(c(110,111,123), size=n*ncol, replace=TRUE), ncol=144))
dim(Activities)
names(Activities) <- c("serial", paste("act1", 1:ncol, sep="_"))

Activities[1:6, 1:11]
  serial act1_1 act1_2 act1_3 act1_4 act1_5 act1_6 act1_7 act1_8 act1_9 act1_10
1      1    111    123    110    110    111    111    111    110    110     110
2      2    123    111    123    110    111    123    123    110    111     110
3      3    111    111    111    111    123    111    123    123    110     123
4      4    123    111    110    111    111    110    123    110    111     111
5      5    110    123    110    111    110    110    111    110    123     111
6      6    111    111    111    123    123    110    123    111    110     123
```

Comment: I don't quite understand "parallel activity" or "secondary, tertiary...". Do you mean two or more activities in a given time interval?  Like watching TV and sleeping at the same time?

Comment: Impossible!  Markov theory says you can only be in one state at any given time. If you _really_ want to do this, then create/define another activity: 110.111 ("sleep+watch TV).